# Dynamically name indexes in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

As most people who work with Sql Server know, you can declare a temporary table like so:

```
create table #foo 
    (
    row_id int identity not null primary key,
    bar varchar(50) not null default 'YoMomma'
    );
```

...this will create a primary key and a default constraint on this temporary table; the names for these objects will be unique, dynamically created by Sql Server.

Is it possible to create a dynamically named index for the table after it's been created?  I have a case where a stored procedure using temporary tables may be running multiple instances at the same time, and I'd like to increase the performance without risking a conflict between identically named objects in the tempdb database.  `CREATE INDEX` command requires an explicit index name.

I am looking for a solution that does not involve dynamic SQL, just dynamic names.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a non issue. Index names only have to be unique within a table scope, not globally across table scopes. Only constraint names have to be unique within an entire database schema.

So, for example, you can run this in multiple concurrent connections with no problems

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
C INT
)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix on #T(C)
```

But this would fail under concurrency

```
ALTER TABLE #T
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (C)
```

Comment: Hmmm... 10 years of working with SQL Server, and I never knew that.  I simply assumed the indexes were treated as objects similar to constraints, but I just tried it and verified that there is no conflict.  Good information!

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - constraints get metadata stored in `sys.objects` which I presume is the reason for the uniqueness requirement but indexes don't.

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to do:

```
CREATE INDEX #foo1 ON #foo(bar);
```

Comment: This does indeed seem to be the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I had to change the answer to @MartinSmith... his answer was more accurate.

Comment: No problem, just glad you found a solution...  Beside, I like Martin